# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InAppBrowser' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I am currently trying to use the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin on my PhoneGap application and I am receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'InAppBrowser' of undefined
```

This is the line that I am trying to call the inAppBrowser from:

```
<button onclick="cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://jmu-nation.myshopify.com/')" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" >SHOP</button>
```

I have imported the package into my project but I am still getting this error when I run it in the browser simulator, and it will not work when I try it on my iOS device.  Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't set name of plugin to config xml.
Should be:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="version" />
```

In features:

For ios:

```
 <feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
```

For Android:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```